# How to select a Solution Configuration within VSTS Build & Release

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In my project i am having few solution configurations as below:

Debug  (defined at `Settings.Debug.xml`)

Release (defined at `Settings.Release.xml`)

Custom (defined at `Settings.Custom.xml`)

How will i select one of the above configuration for a VSTS build & release.

Comment: Can you explain the detail background for your usage? Such as what your project do you want to build/deploy? What's your build/release definition? etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [SlowCheetah transform](https://github.com/Microsoft/slow-cheetah) in your project and then the XML files will be transformed automatically during the build base on the configuration you select when queue the build.